# How to show firstly the filter and then the report in SSRS MS CRM Dynamics 365?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

**Request**: I try to edit the filter of a report when I access to it from a record.

**Context**: I'm in the form of a record and with the ribbon I access to the list of report related to the entity. I click on the report and then it show this:

[image]

So the report show up at first and on the top left there is a button to edit the filter. I don't know if it's possible, but I want to have the filter in the first time AND then the report.

In fact when we access to the report entity records we directly face the filter and then we face the report, I want to know why it's not the same system when I access to it directly from a record.

So is it possible to change this ? If yes how ? Thanks in advance !